# Convert HTML5 canvas to IMG element

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I would like to resize, stretch an HTML5 canvas in a way that the canvas act like an IMG element: set width-height by pixel, percent...

I wonder if is there any way to convert/export an HTML5 canvas to an IMG element, or any way that can make this possible directly on the canvas.

[image: HTML5 CANVAS resize acting like IMG]

I'm using KineticJS library, for details.

Please help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, give your canvas an id (e.g. `example`). Then, using plain JavaScript you can create an image based on that canvas and style it:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('example'),
    dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL(),
    imageFoo = document.createElement('img');
imageFoo.src = dataUrl;

// Style your image here
imageFoo.style.width = '100px';
imageFoo.style.height = '100px';

// After you are done styling it, append it to the BODY element
document.body.appendChild(imageFoo);
```