# equivalent of context.drawImage() with SVG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I have an existing project, and for drawing images it is based on HTML canvas. Now I want to "migrate" in svg, but I don't know how. With canvas I can draw an image simply with

```
context.drawImage(img)
```

where context is an istance of CanvasRenderingContext2D. Is there some sort of context also for SVG?

**EDIT**

I don't want to draw an SVG image into canvas but I want to **replace** the canvas with an SVG element. The reason behind this choice is to improve the quality of images. Drawing a .svg picture on canvas element, it is rendered as a .png or .jpg. Drawing a .svg picture on SVG element, it retains the format, and the result is higher quality.

Comment: There is an `<image>` tag to include other resources. The source may also be a data url.

Comment: In my case I have not default images, they are created and put on canvas at runtime. Is there a class for this tag `<image>`?

Comment: You can copy canvas img data to an img tag (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008473/convert-html5-canvas-to-img-element)

Comment: If the sources are canvas elements, you can either include the canvas directly using `<foreignObject>` or convert to data url and use `<image>`. What to you mean by "class for `<image>`" ? SVG is created more like HTML using tags than canvas using an API.

Comment: My code work in this way : 1) I create an HTML Image object (let's say `img`) 2) I set the source with an URL (`img.src = "./path"`) and after that 3) I call `context.drawImage(img)`. My question is : what is the equivalent way to do this with an SVG element? I mean, if a repeat the first two steps, how can I continue? I think is not possible to do the same with SVG

Comment: The same i.e. 1) Create an SVG image object (an image rather than an img). 2 set the source (in this case it's xlink:href) 3) call context.drawImage(image). You do need an image though you can't do it with arbitrary inline SVG.

Comment: If you were able to do what you desire it would be a privacy hole in the browser. You should report it and we'll "fix" it so you can't do it any more.