# How can I convert Canvas OR Data in any div to Image in Ionic Framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic Framework, I need to create an image from data received form the server, which will be displayed in a div. I want to convert that data into image. Can any one please help me step by step?

Comment: This is very broad, and requests for tutorials aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow. Can you clarify which part of the process you do not know how to do?

Comment: Well I want to convert a canvas or div to image.

Comment: Which part of the process are you stuck with? What do you already have?

Comment: I havn't worked that much because I didn't find any related Plugin for this purpose, Thats why I asked on Stackoverflow.
I just created a canvas
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300px" height="300px">
<h3>Sample Text</h3>
</canvas>
Now I want to convert this canvas into Image.

Comment: OK, there seems to be a lot out there when searching `convert canvas to image`, that might work for you? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008473/convert-html5-canvas-to-img-element