# Can I use a FontAwesome character as favicon in XHTML?

Tags: html, jsf, font-awesome, favicon

I create a XHTML page with `<h:outputStylesheet name="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />` so it loads the icon automatically like thiscase of `i class="fa fa-truck"`

I'd like to add the favicon **fa-truck** to my XHTML page, I download the icon and use this:

```
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{resource['icons/truck.png']}" />
```

But, I'm looking for another solution without download the icon, I'd like to load it from `class="fa fa-truck"`. So, I'd like that link `rel="icon" type="image/png"` uses this class directly without download or compress or convert, exactly like `i` does. In other meaning it's possible to replace `href` by `class` ? like this:

It's possible ?. Could you please help me ?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're not keen on latest versions of FontAwsome, you can use the built in version of FontAwsome in Primefaces. Currently `Primefaces-6.1` ships with `FontAwsome-4.6.1`. You can enable this feature by setting a `context-param` `primefaces.FONT_AWESOME` to `true` at your `web.xml`

Comment: Hello @KishorPrakash, thanks for your reply. I added to web.xml `<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>` and I added on my XHTML `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" class="fa fa-truck"/>` but the favicon won't change, could you please help me ?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Font Awesome Icon As Favicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156240/use-font-awesome-icon-as-favicon)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to use a FontAwesome (or any other font that happens to contain icons) character as is as a favicon.

From the W3C documentation:

> the format for the image you have chosen must be 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels, using either 8-bit or 24-bit colors. The format of the image must be one of PNG (a W3C standard), GIF, or ICO.

So you need to convert the character to a supported image file.

See also:

- https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon
- http://caniuse.com/#search=favicon
- [Font Awesome Favicon Generator](https://paulferrett.com/fontawesome-favicon/)

Answer (score 1):

You can compress truck.png https://tinypng.com/

And after u can convert to base64 https://www.base64-image.de

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,...."/>
```

Comment: Hello Sir @moon93, thanks for your reply, but It seems that I won't describe enough my problem. I create a XHTML page with `<h:outputStylesheet name="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />` so it loads the icon automatically like the case of `<i class="fa fa-truck"></i>` . Now, I'd like that `<link rel="icon" type="image/png"` uses this class directly without download or compress or convert, exactly like `<i />` does. In other meaning it's possible to replace **href** by **class** ?. Have you please any idea. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to:

- Create a regular `i` with the icon you want to set as favicon.
- Convert this `i` to a canvas, for example with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).
- [Convert the canvas to a regular `img`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008473/convert-html5-canvas-to-img-element#answer-18008563).
- Set this `img` as the favicon, for example with [favicon.js](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/).